# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running maven jgroups project build with netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, classnotfoundexception, jgroups

I am making a chat project. When i run it inside ide (netbeans) it opens normally and works great. But when i run it from terminal i'm getting error like this:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jgroups/Receiver`
`at com.mycompany.chatapp1.ChatWindow.<init>(ChatWindow.java:32)`
`at com.mycompany.chatapp1.Main.main(Main.java:10)`
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jgroups.Receiver`
`at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)`
`at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)`
`at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)`
`at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)`
`at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)`
`at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)`
`at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)`
`... 2 more`

I run it by command `java -jar ChatApp1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

And here is my dependency info:
`<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>`

What could be wrong?

Comment: It seems that your dependent jars are missing when you run stuff throough command prompt

Comment: What should I change to run it with the same command?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you want to use command prompt when everything works fine on you IDE??

Comment: I just wanted to run it from desktop, not from ide :)

Answer (score 5):

When you create a jar project, dependent projects are not included. So you would either need to set the classpath on the commandline via `-cp` which would be quite cumbersome, or you could use the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), which includes all your dependencies in you jar, resulting in a complete, executable jar file.

Include the following snippet in your pom (of course with your main class):

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Oh, man, you are awesome :D Have seen this code before, but choosed the shorther version. Thank you very much for explaining!

Comment: finally a solution that works! thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of an Integrated Development Environment is to setup and manage your source code and its dependencies.

Eclipse does this one way, Netbeans does it another way, and so does IntelliJ.

You can try to reproduce it by simulating Eclipse's Deployment Assembly. Find out where your libraries and source code is stored. Use those directories for your javac command. Then execute java with the class you want that contains a main method.

This gets harder if your project is meant to be a web application.

You really should let the IDE do it for you.

Comment: "You really should let the IDE do it for you." - And then you will have no idea how the IDE is doing it, so that every time something goes wrong (and it will) will be another mad scramble through documentation of not just basic Java, but the huge complicated mess that every IDE actually is. It would be really, really nice to let the IDE do it. But when the IDE spits out a cryptic error message like this, you're still supposed to know what it means and fix it yourself. An IDE is a shortcut, not the infallible wizard that always makes your project work.