# Run Maven project shows error "NoClassDefFoundError: purejavacomm/CommPortIdentifier"

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, command-line, serial-port

I have write a serial port code using "purejavacomm-0.0.22.jar",if running via NetBeans id 8.0.2 Build Success output came

```
[ttyUSB0, ttyS3, ttyS2, ttyS1, ttyS0]
```

But I have using via terminal

```
mvn package
```

**[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS**
but running the project

```
java -jar target/PureJavaComm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I will get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: purejavacomm/CommPortIdentifier
    at com.mycompany.purejavacommu.PureJavaComm.main(PureJavaComm.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: purejavacomm.CommPortIdentifier
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>PureJavaComm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <mainClass>com.mycompany.purejavacommu.PureJavaComm</mainClass>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparetimelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>purejavacomm</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.purejavacommu.PureJavaComm</mainClass>                            
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>          
            </plugin>
        </plugins>  
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is m2_repo path variable is set on netbeans, so it runs ok while coding but once you have your jar compiled it doesn't know where to search the PureJavaComm library

Comment: How to set m2_repo path in mvn package.

Answer (score 0):

The ClassNotFoundException indicates that the class is not found on the classpath when you are trying to execute the program. You should add the purejavacomm library to the classpath at runtime. One way to do that is via command line -cp modifier:

`-cp target/lib/<dependency> -jar ...`

So in your case it might end up looking like:

```
java -cp target/lib/purejavacomm.jar -jar target/PureJavaComm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Apache Maven Shade Plugin:
This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Ref this solution [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running maven jgroups project build with netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990475/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-running-maven-jgroups-project-build-with-net/22991108#22991108)